# Strategy with multiple TFs clarification

Tags: pine-script

I'm curious how TV treats a strategy with multiple TFs applied to a single TF, more specifically how higher TF data will be calculated on a lower TF strategy. Like for example I have strategy that uses a couple of momentum indicators on the 15 min and 5 min (the strategy being applied to the 5 min) and when I plot 15 min data on the 5 min chart it appears to be calculating the 15 min data how they closed on each 5 minute during the 15 minute. So the calculations are now more dynamic than how static I expected them to be throughout the whole 15 min on the 5 min chart.

This hasn't always been the case for me since I worked on multiple strategies and they gave me varying results when working on multiple TFs. Can anyone explain to me how these multiple TF strategies should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you describe looks like what you will get if you use the wrong method illustrated in this code. For a `security()` call's result to be correct, all relevant calcs must be executed in the higher TF context of the `security()` call:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © PineCoders
//@version=4
study("")
tf = "15"
p = 20
r = rsi(close, p)

// Good but repaints.
rsi15 = security(syminfo.ticker, tf, r)
plot(rsi15, "rsi15 Repaints", color.silver)

// Good and doesn't repaint.
rsi15NoRepaint = security(syminfo.ticker, tf, r[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(rsi15NoRepaint, "►rsi15 No Repaint◄", color.lime, 6, transp = 50)

// Wrong.
close15 = security(syminfo.ticker, tf, close)
rsiWrong = rsi(close15, p)
plot(rsiWrong, "rsi Wrong", color.red)

plot(r, "Simple rsi ", color.blue)
```

[image]

Comment: ```
// Good and doesn't repaint.
rsi15NoRepaint = security(syminfo.ticker, tf, r[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(rsi15NoRepaint, "►rsi15 No Repaint◄", color.lime, 6, transp = 50)
```
I don't need to apply this on the smaller TF to prevent repaint in general, right?

Comment: The choice of the repainting/no repainting flavor of the higher TF is up to you and will depend on how you are using that higher TF signal. If your goal is to generate alerts on crosses of it, then the no-repainting version will produce more reliable results. For the chart's TF, you are not using `security()` so can't apply the same method to prevent repainting. See [How to avoid repainting when NOT using security()](https://www.tradingview.com/script/s8kWs84i-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-NOT-using-security/) for a discussion of the considerations to be aware of.